# UTF-8 read file parsed differently when outside ide

Tags: java, string, gradle, utf-8, libgdx

*TL;DR:
String parsed from file is different in distribution build than in the IDE build.*

So the input is a file with UTF-8 encoded characters.

Here is a small sample of the file:

```
而已,éryǐ,3,2,20,/that's all/nothing more/
值得,zhíde,3,2,20,/to be worth/to deserve/
稳定,wěndìng,3,2,20,/steady/stable/stability/to stabilize/to pacify/
年轻,niánqīng,3,2,20,/young/
不仅,bùjǐn,3,2,20,/not only (this one)/not just (...) but also/
永远,yǒngyuǎn,3,2,20,/forever/eternal/
放心,fàngxīn,3,2,20,/to feel relieved/to feel reassured/to be at ease/
```

The file is read in like this:

```
    FileHandle f = Gdx.files.internal("vocabulary.txt");
    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                f.read(), "UTF-8"));

        char[] buf = new char[512];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while((bytesRead = br.read(buf, 0, 512)) != -1)
        {
            sb.append(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String fs = sb.toString();
```

Now to test that the file is being read correctly, this code is written:

```
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
System.err.println(s.length());
System.err.println(bytes.length);
```

The output should be:

```
104927
116045
```

The first number represents the number of characters in the string.
The second number represents the number of bytes in the string.

The different numbers come from some characters being 1 byte and others being multiple bytes.

The output I get in the IDE is the expected output. However the output i get after distributing the jar file and running with the `java -jar` command is as such:

```
104927
104927
```

It seems like the string is formatted wrong because the bytes equals the characters. My theory is that for some reason the the String in distribution mode is losing data by sticking every character into 1 byte.

More info:

```
IDE: Intellij idea
Libraries: LibGDX, Gradle (distributed with the `gradlew desktop:dist` command)
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"


    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "chi"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.4'
        roboVMVersion = '2.2.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"        
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Edits:

- The function is almost equivalent to LibGDX's file.readString()
- Testing is done on the same computer.
- Files are the same size now. It was a newline error.

Comment: Is [this the same GDX](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.java#L197)? If so, it has a method to read the file into a string with a specified character set, and it looks basically identical to yours. When you say "*after distributing the jar file*" - are you testing on a different computer, or the same one? Do you have any guess why the output count is +2 higher than the character count? (Does the file have a Unicode BOM at the start?) Have you done any test to try and print it, or step through and see where it starts to differ?

Comment: `s.getBytes()` uses the platform’s default charset.  Specify an explicit charset to get consistent behavior.

Answer (score 1):

@VGR solved it. Needed to use getBytes("UTF-8")`.